# How to run function on subsets of matrix

Tags: r, split-apply-combine

I have a data.frame that contains subsets of data. These subsets are identified by an ID stored in a column called MASTStation. Here's an example from my data.

```
> Dummy4
   Key MASTStation Longitude Latitude  z Pressure Temperature Salinity   SigmaT SigmaTheta    PAR ChlAFluor
1    1      CH-A01  -168.497   65.998  0        0     1.80255 32.53150 26.00931   26.00931 35.844    5.6362
2    2      CH-A01  -168.497   65.998 -1        1     1.80255 32.53150 26.00931   26.00932 35.844    5.6362
3    3      CH-A01  -168.497   65.998 -2        2     1.80255 32.53150 26.00942   26.00943 35.844    5.5869
4    4      CH-A01  -168.497   65.998 -3        3     1.80190 32.53240 26.00935   26.00936 21.383    5.8863
5    5      CH-A01  -168.497   65.998 -4        4     1.80220 32.53250 26.00929   26.00931 16.383    5.9729
6  782      CH-H02  -167.048   69.493  0        0     7.71730 31.10890 24.26078   24.26079 25.697    1.5285
7  783      CH-H02  -167.048   69.493 -1        1     7.71730 31.10890 24.26078   24.26081 25.697    1.5285
8  784      CH-H02  -167.048   69.493 -2        2     7.71730 31.10890 24.25936   24.25939 25.697    1.5127
9  785      CH-H02  -167.048   69.493 -3        3     7.72100 31.10885 24.26016   24.26021 22.246    1.4385
10 786      CH-H02  -167.048   69.493 -4        4     7.72125 31.11020 24.26036   24.26042 17.901    1.4320
```

I have a function that I want to apply to each of these subsets, so I tried to use by() like so:

```
by(Dummy4,list(Dummy4[,2]),calculate.mld,Dummy4[,9],Dummy4[,5])
```

Which returns the following error and traceback():

```
Error in FUN(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) : 
  sigma and z vectors must have equal length 
11 stop("sigma and z vectors must have equal length") 
10 FUN(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...) 
9 FUN(X[[1L]], ...) 
8 lapply(X = split(X, group), FUN = FUN, ...) 
7 tapply(seq_len(10L), list(structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CH-A01", "CH-H02"), class = "factor")), 
    function (x) 
    FUN(data[x, , drop = FALSE], ...), simplify = TRUE) 
6 eval(expr, envir, enclos) 
5 eval(substitute(tapply(seq_len(nd), IND, FUNx, simplify = simplify)), 
    data) 
4 structure(eval(substitute(tapply(seq_len(nd), IND, FUNx, simplify = simplify)), 
    data), call = match.call(), class = "by") 
3 by.data.frame(Dummy4, list(Dummy4[, 2]), calculate.mld, Dummy4[, 
    9], Dummy4[, 5]) 
2 by(Dummy4, list(Dummy4[, 2]), calculate.mld, Dummy4[, 9], Dummy4[, 
    5]) 
1 as.matrix(by(Dummy4, list(Dummy4[, 2]), calculate.mld, Dummy4[, 
    9], Dummy4[, 5]))
```

So the problem is with my function. However, when I split the matrix into two separate matrices based on the subsets, and run the function on each of those matrices, there are no problems. This is my function:

```
> calculate.mld
function(sigma, z, deltaSigma = 0.125) 
    { 
        # check that the number of sigma and z values are equal 
        if (length(sigma) != length(z)) 
        { 
            stop('sigma and z vectors must have equal length') 
        }
        # remove the na's 
        keepers <- !(is.na(z) | is.na(sigma)) 
        z <- z[keepers] 
        sigma <- sigma[keepers] 
        # return an NA and a warning if there aren't at least two 
        # numeric values 
        if (length(sigma) < 2) 
        { 
            warning('fewer than two valid sigma and depth-value combinations entered, NA returned') 
            NA 
        } else { 
            # I use negative depths to be consistent with the Scripps database 
            if (all(z >= 0)) 
            { 
                z <- z * -1 
                pos <- TRUE 
            } else { 
                pos <- FALSE 
            } 
            # be sure the data are sorted by depths 
            ord <- order(z, decreasing = TRUE) 
            z <- z[ord] 
            sigma <- sigma[ord] 
            #z <- sort(z, decreasing = TRUE) 
            #sigma <- sigma[order(z, decreasing = TRUE)] 
            # Manuscript uses a z of 10 m as the initial sigmaRef, but we will 
            # take the closest value in case the 10-m measurement is missing. 
            minDepth <- which(abs(z + 10) == min(abs(z + 10))) 
            minDepth <- ifelse(length(minDepth) > 1, minDepth[2], minDepth) 
            sigmaRef <- sigma[minDepth] 
            sigma <- sigma[minDepth:length(sigma)] 
            z <- z[minDepth:length(z)] 
            diffs <- abs(sigma - sigmaRef) 
            # if sigma never changes by at least deltaSigma, return the lowest depth 
            # Otherwise proceed 
            if (max(diffs, na.rm = TRUE) >= deltaSigma) 
            { 
                # the uniform region, if present, occurs where the change between 
                # any two points is <= deltaSigma * 1/10, and the change in sigma over 
                # the profile has not yet exceeded deltaSigma 
                uniformRegion <- (abs(sigma[2:length(sigma)] - 
                                          sigma[1:(length(sigma) - 1)]) <= 
                                      (deltaSigma / 10)) & 
                    (diffs[2:length(diffs)] < deltaSigma) 
                if (any(uniformRegion)) 
                { 
                    sigmaRefPos <- max(which(uniformRegion)) 
                    # change sigmaRef to the base of the uniform region 
                    sigmaRef <- sigma[sigmaRefPos] 
                    # calculate change from the new reference 
                    reachedDeltaSigma <- abs(sigma[(sigmaRefPos + 1):length(sigma)] - sigmaRef) >= deltaSigma 
                    # if any deeper measurements of sigma reach or exceed deltaSigma, 
                    # linearly interpolate between the nearest points to find 
                    # mixed-layer depth 
                    if (any(reachedDeltaSigma)) 
                    { 
                        pair <- min(which(reachedDeltaSigma)) + sigmaRefPos - 1 
                        linmod <- lm(z[c(pair, pair + 1)] ~ sigma[c(pair, pair + 1)]) 
                        mld <- as.vector(linmod$coefficients[1] + 
                                             linmod$coefficients[2] * 
                                             (sigmaRef + deltaSigma)) 
                    } else { 
                        # otherwise, mixed-layer depth is the deepest point 
                        mld <- min(z) 
                    } 
                } else { 
                    # if there is no uniform region, just linearly interpolate mld 
                    pair <- min(which(diffs >= deltaSigma)) - 1 
                    linmod <- lm(z[c(pair, pair + 1)] ~ sigma[c(pair, pair + 1)]) 
                    mld <- as.vector(linmod$coefficients[1] + 
                                         linmod$coefficients[2] * 
                                         (sigmaRef + deltaSigma)) 
                } 
            } else { 
                mld <- min(z) 
            } 
            if (pos) mld <- abs(mld) 
            mld 
        } 
    }
```

I don't understand why the two variable columns no longer have equal length when running the function using by(). I'm sure it's a simple enough solution, but I'm not seeing it. Any ideas?

I'm a beginner at R, so please bear with me on this.

Comment: You don't appear to have a matrix. It looks like you have a data.frame.

Comment: My bad on that one. I converted it to a matrix and still have the same problem.

Comment: You really shouldn't convert to a matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can use `by` here. You need a function that acccepts a data.frame as argument:

```
by(Dummy4, list(Dummy4$MASTStation), function(df) calculate.mld(df$SigmaT, df$z))
#: CH-A01
#[1] -4
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
#: CH-H02
#[1] -4
```

I'd prefer using package data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Dummy4)
Dummy4[, .(MLD = calculate.mld(SigmaT, z)), by = MASTStation]
#   MASTStation MLD
#1:      CH-A01  -4
#2:      CH-H02  -4
```

Reproducible data (created with `dput`):

```
Dummy4 <- structure(list(Key = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 782L, 783L, 784L, 
785L, 786L), MASTStation = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CH-A01", "CH-H02"), class = "factor"), 
    Longitude = c(-168.497, -168.497, -168.497, -168.497, -168.497, 
    -167.048, -167.048, -167.048, -167.048, -167.048), Latitude = c(65.998, 
    65.998, 65.998, 65.998, 65.998, 69.493, 69.493, 69.493, 69.493, 
    69.493), z = c(0L, -1L, -2L, -3L, -4L, 0L, -1L, -2L, -3L, 
    -4L), Pressure = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L
    ), Temperature = c(1.80255, 1.80255, 1.80255, 1.8019, 1.8022, 
    7.7173, 7.7173, 7.7173, 7.721, 7.72125), Salinity = c(32.5315, 
    32.5315, 32.5315, 32.5324, 32.5325, 31.1089, 31.1089, 31.1089, 
    31.10885, 31.1102), SigmaT = c(26.00931, 26.00931, 26.00942, 
    26.00935, 26.00929, 24.26078, 24.26078, 24.25936, 24.26016, 
    24.26036), SigmaTheta = c(26.00931, 26.00932, 26.00943, 26.00936, 
    26.00931, 24.26079, 24.26081, 24.25939, 24.26021, 24.26042
    ), PAR = c(35.844, 35.844, 35.844, 21.383, 16.383, 25.697, 
    25.697, 25.697, 22.246, 17.901), ChlAFluor = c(5.6362, 5.6362, 
    5.5869, 5.8863, 5.9729, 1.5285, 1.5285, 1.5127, 1.4385, 1.432
    )), .Names = c("Key", "MASTStation", "Longitude", "Latitude", 
"z", "Pressure", "Temperature", "Salinity", "SigmaT", "SigmaTheta", 
"PAR", "ChlAFluor"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much. The data.table package looks like it will be very useful to me in the future